# how to prove that trace is the unique linear transformation T: R(n*n) to R such that $T(p) = rank(p)$ for every idempotent P(where $p^2 = p$)

Tags: linear-algebra

how to prove that trace is the unique linear transformation such that $T(p) = rank(p)$ for every idempotent P